# ADB over wifi/hotspot not working

Tags: android, linux, adb

i follow this guide on my non-rooted phone but not working>> [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

**Here is my Output**

`[stark]:~|$ adb kill-server
[stark]:~|$ adb tcpip 5555
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
[stark]:~|$ adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555
connected to 192.168.43.1:5555
[stark]:~|$ THEN I REMOVE USB^C
[stark]:~|$ adb shell
**error: device not found**`

I tried many times but always getting error that device not Found

**I have Android N, Current OS: Ubuntu, ADB version: 1.0.31**

Comment: use wifi adb application and then try this

Comment: @Kaushal28 i tried this app >> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en follow instruction but getting device not found error

Comment: you need root for this app.

Comment: @Kaushal28 one month ago this method works fine, on that time i have MM installed. but now I have android N, and not working.

Comment: @Kaushal28 however i rooted my mobile, but still wifi adb app is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have upgraded the phone from `MM` to `N`, therefore to get it working, you have to root it again. You can check whether your phone is rooted or not using any root checker app.

Comment: my phone is not rooted. while im on MM my phone not rooted that time too. And adb over hotspot worked very well. but after update to N maybe adb over hotspot not work or not supported. can you confirm that adb over hotspot/wifi works in android N?

Comment: @TonyStark read the `requirements` section of the app on play store. They have clearly written that: `This app works on ROOTED devices only`

Comment: Bro. i read. okay that app works in rooted mobile. but adb over wifi actually works without root. and i tested on MM. But dont know why its not work in android N

Comment: Make sure u've given all the permissions then.

Comment: open the info. of the app and check that required permissions are given.

Comment: that app dont ask permissions. anyway that app is actually optional. without that app it should be work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem started after upgrading android studio. Wifi Adb extension on android studio used to work just fine before upgrading . All the extensions attached below were working fine . I haven't rooted my phone at all. [WIFI ADB EXTENSIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfB4n.png)